# Floated+cleared element not affecting following floated elements in IE7 - is there a workaround?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float, internet-explorer-6

I'm trying to style a definition list so that `dt` tags start new rows, and can be followed by any number of `dd` elements on the same row. In modern browsers this is as simple as

```
dt {
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
dd {
    float:left;
}
```

In IE7, however, if the clearing element has float, subsequent floats are not affected. ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/bmNQe/)) Is there any workaround for this bug? I've been looking around, but none of the solutions usually suggested seem applicable:

- since this is a definition list, I can't wrap elements on the same rows in a `div`.
- I don't want to use an invisible non-floated clearing element - it would have to be a `dt` or `dd`, and the whole point of using a definition listr instead of a table or `span`-`br` soup is to have semantic markup, which would be messed up by purely presentational `dt`/`dd` elements.
- as far as I can see, approaches based on triggering [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) (thus triggering inline-block behavior) such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365401/ie7-clear-float-issue/3365509#3365509) don't work when the number of elements per row is not fixed. (Also, I would prefer not to bother with stripping whitespace.)
- I couldn't get [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614566/ie7-and-ie8-float-clearing-without-adding-empty-elements/2615009#2615009) to work with `dl` instead of `ul`; even setting `display:list-item` didn't help.

Is there any other way to force IE7 to mimic standard float behavior?

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood you original post when I answered, but in any case, I don't see the behavior you describe in firefox with the above CSS. Code and output: http://imgur.com/mlLiy.png

Comment: @Nathan Taylor: sorry, I had the two styles swapped up (though the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bmNQe/) I gave was correct). Fixed now.

Comment: Have you tried inline-block yet?

Comment: Do you *have* to use the dt/dd?

Comment: @Nathan Taylor: I would prefer to, it is the semantically meaningful way in various situations where you have a label and one or more items (e. g. form fields) associated to it. I can use the `ul`-based solution I mentioned if all else fails, but I thought maybe there is a hack for this. (It is hard to find workarounds for IE7 float problems by googling, because it has some very common float bugs, and results for those drown out the less common ones.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [inline-block](http://work.arounds.org/issue/18/using-inline-block-ie7-and-ie6/) instead of floats.

```
dl { 
    line-height:1.2em; 
    padding-left:1em; 
} 
dt { 
    display:block; 
    margin:0 0 -1.2em -1em; 
} 

dd { 
    display:inline-block; 
    display:inline !ie; 
    margin-left:1em; 
}
```

Credit to deathshadow who came up with this.

Comment: Could you give an example or more details?

Comment: The example is in the link.... ( i was the one that added it ). Do you have trouble understanding the link?

Comment: That is a description of how to achieve inline-block behavior in IE6/7. How do you use inline blocks to simulate floats? More specifically, how do you tell an inline block to start on a new line?

Comment: Oh, misunderstood the purpose. Hm, you could throw an element in between before each `dt` to clear it, but you don't want to do that. You could also use multiple `dl` elements, but maybe you don't want to do that. I don't think there is a proper clean solution to this.